# VS 2015 Can't deploy in my device

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I'm starting developing with VS Comunity 2015 and when I try to deploy my Cordova App on my windows phone 8.1 I get this error:

> Error : DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: The provided package is already installed, and reinstallation of the package was blocked. Check the AppXDeployment-Server event log for details. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073CFB)

this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx) from msdn says something but I'm not sure if I'm fixing what it says.

I tried to change the name and version of my app in the `config.xml` file but didn't work.

Comment: I assume you've successfully deployed before. Have you tried manually unistalling the app from your phone?

Comment: Nop, there is no app installed :|

Comment: Is there any other app from you installed? Or a published version of this one?

Comment: Did you look at the event log? What did it say?